# ForkJoinTask: Order of join()-ing

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, fork-join, forkjoinpool

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html) of `ForkJoinTask` says:

> [R]eturns (joins) should be performed innermost-first. For example, a.fork(); b.fork(); b.join(); a.join(); is likely to be substantially more efficient than joining a before b.

I can't quite get my head around as to why (and in which circumstances) the order of `join()`s would matter, assuming I need to join `a` **and** `b` and get their results before continuing my computations.

Specifically, I have a couple dozens `fork()`ed tasks and I need to wait for *all* of them to return their result; much like `invokeAll()` would do, but I can still perform some work after `fork()`ing but before `join()`ing, so I implemented something like a `joinAll()` to be called only when I know that I cannot continue without the results from the forked tasks.

The question is, how should this `joinAll()` be implemented? Does it matter in which order this code actually calls `join()` on the tasks?

Comment: You may want to post this question to the concurrency interest forum (if you're not a member, sign up here: concurrency-interest.cs.oswego.edu) You may even get Doug Lea to answer it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While preparing the ForkJoin-Framework for a lecture, I also stumbled upon this statement in the docs and wanted to know why it is that way.

First, I want to note, that I do not have the definitive answer to your question, but want to share what I found:

In the original paper written by Doug Lea (http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/papers/fj.pdf), his implementation of the Work-Stealing algorithm is described more in detail in section 2.1: Subtasks generated by worker threads (using `fork`) are **pushed onto their own deque**. The worker threads process their **own deque LIFO** (youngest-first), while workers steal from other deques FIFO (oldest-first).

And then the important part I think is: "When a worker thread encounters a `join`  operation, **it processes other tasks**, if available, **until the target task is noticed** to have completed (via isDone). All tasks otherwise run to completion without blocking."

Therefore, it is more efficient to first `join` on the tasks which the worker itself will process next, instead of `join`ing on other tasks which might be stolen from other workers. Otherwise there is probably more thread management overhead due to potential context switches and lock contention.

At least for me, this reasoning would make sense regarding the description in the JavaDoc.

Comment: Thanks for your input. After reading some more about work stealing I have come to the same conclusion, i.e. to try and avoid work stealing actually happening. Glad you confirm my thoughts in this regard :)